# Event listener responds to first click, but does not execute .addClass() until second click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on the event listener (#bar) the console.log fires but the .addClass() doesn't. I looked through some threads on the topic but found nothing that helped.

```js
$("#bar").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log("click")
  $("#bar").addClass("bar-open");
});
```

```css
#bar {
    overflow-y: clip;
    height: 48px;
    transition: height 1s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1005;
    background-color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
    border: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bar-open {
    height: 365px !important;
}

.hidden-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span> This a reveal button </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-section">
    <div>
      This is a bunch of hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works on my end, when I click the height is modified. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: Firefox, but it behaves the same way in Chrome.

Comment: That's weird, not only because your code is correct but also because my comment got "upvoted", meaning it's working for multiple people. You confirm that clicking on the reveal button doesn't change the height and so doesn't display the hidden content ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
$("#bar").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log("click")
  $(this).addClass("bar-open");
  console.log($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

```css
#bar {
    overflow-y: clip;
    height: 48px;
    transition: height 1s;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1005;
    background-color: rgb(248, 249, 250);
    border: 1px solid rgb(222, 226, 230);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.bar-open {
    height: 365px !important;
}

.hidden-section {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar">
  <div>
    <div>
      <span> This a reveal button </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden-section">
    <div>
      This is a bunch of hidden content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```